# Is there something with the same function as animationEnd for infinite CSS animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I've got this small script that sends out an alert that says "done!" when an animation is finished.

Is there a function that will do the same for infinite animations, ie. execute something every time a loop ends?

http://jsfiddle.net/RJ55N/

JavaScript:

```
$('#dot1').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',   
   function(e) {

   alert('done!');

  });
```

CSS:

```
#dot1{
   width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:black;
    animation:one 1s 1; 
}

@keyframes one {
    from {width:10px; height:10px; }
     to {width:100px; height:100px; }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into [callback functions](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp)?

Comment: Just started! And I found the answer pretty quickly. I had tried using AnimationIteration before, but I guess I was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the W3C standard method of doing it, using the `animationiteration` event:

```js
$('#dot1').on('animationiteration', function (e) {
  alert('done!')
})
```

If you care about browser support, you can add listeners for the following events too:

- Webkit `webkitAnimationIteration`
- Opera `oanimationiteration`
- IE `MSAnimationIteration`

Comment: Important to note that if you're writing a more generic function, the iteration event only occurs on looping animations, so combining the looping and ending functions ensures that something gets fired.